# jquery ajax success not working

Tags: ajax, jquery, cross-domain, jsonp

I got simple ajax call i could not get why it is not running success method despite the fact that chrome developer tools show that it is getting the response for the request.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var url_API="http://moviesapi.herokuapp.com/cinemas/find/"+"PL15RH";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url_API,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        crossDomain:true,
        success: function (response) {             
            alert(1);
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: are you sure getting the response as json

Comment: you can check the response by putting http://moviesapi.herokuapp.com/cinemas/find/PL15RH in ur browser

Comment: it doesn't look like the API is supporting jsonp

Comment: http://moviesapi.herokuapp.com/cinemas/find/PL15RH. try this url and also change response to some other variable name also jsonp to json

Comment: 500 Internal server error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The API doesn't support jsonp. You're getting `500 (Internal Server Error)`.
2. It does support JSON, but you're getting the classic `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` CORS error. You need to explicitly send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on your heroku API:

Header property:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

A more verbose solution: ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-w)

Comment: Apparently not, because it's still throwing the same CORS error.

Comment: remus is right, check https://github.com/nickcharlton/moviesapi sourcecode, and you won't find any presence of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header set up presence.

Comment: no it support json: check it go to: http://moviesapi.herokuapp.com/cinemas/find/PL15RH

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var url_API="http://moviesapi.herokuapp.com/cinemas/find/"+"PL15RH";
        $.ajax({
           type: 'GET',
           url: url_API,
           dataType: "json",
           crossDomain:true,
           success: function (response) {             
            alert(response);
        }

    });
});
```